# What's the connection between the two "Fast Walsh Transform"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, linear-algebra, fourier-transform, matrix

First Let's take a look at the convolution $\displaystyle C _ { i } = \sum _ { j \oplus k = i } A _ { j } * B _ { k }$, and the $\oplus$represents any boolean operation. And we are able to evaluate $C$ in $O(n \log n)$ time, using an algorithm called **Fast Walsh Transform**, where $n$ represents the length of the binary digits.

However, when looking at [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform), it says that the Walsh Transform is to accelerate the evaluation of an $n \times n$ Matrix called Walsh Matrix. I also found it reasonable.

My question is, what's the connection between the two evaluations? I know that a convolution is a linear transformation and can be represented as a vector multiplied by a matrix. But **where's the matrix in the First convolution**? I am so confused, and does it represent that some multiplications with specified matrixed could be accelerated to $O(n \log n)$? (Thus the matrix is $n \times n$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are vectors of length $n$, where $n$ is a power of 2. We index $A$ and $B$ using binary vectors of length $\log_2 n$, and define their convolution $C$ as
$$
C_i = \sum_{j \oplus k = i} A_j B_k.
$$

You can calculate the convolution of $A$ and $B$ using the following algorithm:

- Compute the Walsh transform of $A$: $\alpha = H_n A$.
- Compute the Walsh transform of $B$: $\beta = H_n B$.
- Multiply $\alpha$ and $\beta$ pointwise: $\gamma(S) = \alpha(S)\beta(S)$ for all $S$.
- Compute the inverse Walsh transform of $\gamma$: $C = H_n^{-1} \gamma$.

(Note that up to normalization, $H_n^{-1}$ and $H_n$ are the same matrix.)

The way we compute the convolution of $A$ and $B$ is using the Walsh transform and its inverse. The Walsh transform itself simply consists of multiplying a vector by the Walsh matrix, which can be done in $O(n\log n)$ time. Since the third step takes only $O(n)$ time, the entire algorithm runs in $O(n\log n)$.

Comment: but, where's the boolean operation? Also does the multiplication takes less than $O(n^2)$ time?

Comment: The Boolean operation (which is actually *not* arbitrary) is the one used to define the convolution.

Comment: The multiplication can be done in time $O(n)$.

Comment: I mean that, if I calculate $\displaystyle C _ { i } = \sum _ { j \text{&} k = i } A _ { j } * B _ { k }$ and $\displaystyle C _ { i } = \sum _ { j\ xor\ k = i } A _ { j } * B _ { k }$, would the same Walsh matrix take effect?

Comment: or the matrix to multiply is not fixed? But thus the **Walsh Matrix** is fixed...

Comment: Your claim that convolution can be computed in $O(n\log n)$ for *any* binary operation is unsubstantiated. It is true if $\oplus$ is XOR, and in some other cases (corresponding to FFT, for example).

Comment: I see, but the last question is if those three binary operations (and, xor, or) represents different walsh matrixes?

Comment: There is only one Walsh matrix, which corresponds to XOR.

Comment: It seems that the matrixes which correspond to **and** and **or** have the same specifications as walsh matrix

Comment: There’s only one Walsh matrix. What you do with it is up to you.